# Get Values From Complex Class Using Reflection

Tags: c#, xml, reflection

I have a class, which is created and populated from an xml string, I've simplified it for example purposes:

```
[XmlRoot("Person")]
public sealed class Person
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Emails", Type = typeof(PersonEmails)]
    public PersonEmails Emails { get; set; }
}

public class PersonEmails
{
    [XmlElement("Email", Type = typeof(PersonEmail))]
    public PersonEmail[] Emails { get; set; }
}

public class PersonEmail
{
    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

To extract the information, I'm trying to load them into another class, which is simply:

```
public class TransferObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObjectField[] Fields { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm only populating "Fields" from the other object, which would simply be (Name = "Location", Value = "London"), but for Emails, (Name = "Email"+Type, Value = jeff@here.com)

Currently I can populate all the other fields, but I'm stuck with Emails, and knowing how to dig deep enough to be able to use reflection (or not) to get the information I need.  Currently I'm using:

```
Person person = Person.FromXmlString(xmlString);
List<ObjectField> fields = new List<ObjectField>();
foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in person.getType().GetProperties()
{
    fields.Add(new ObjectField { Name = pinfo.Name, Value = pinfo.getValue(person, null).ToString();
}
```

How can I expand on the above to add all my emails to the list?

Comment: Why does the value need to be a string?

Comment: The TransferObject eventually becomes an XML String, which is passed to a web service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to type cast a complex values type to string value so you lost the data. Instead use following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.Name = "Person One";
        person.Location = "India";
        person.Emails = new PersonEmails();
        person.Phones = new PersonPhones();
        person.Emails.Emails = new PersonEmail[] { new PersonEmail() { Type = "Official", Value = "xyz@official.com" }, new PersonEmail() { Type = "Personal", Value = "xyz@personal.com" } };
        person.Phones.Phones = new PersonPhone[] { new PersonPhone() { Type = "Official", Value = "789-456-1230" }, new PersonPhone() { Type = "Personal", Value = "123-456-7890" } };

        List<ObjectField> fields = new List<ObjectField>();

        fields = GetPropertyValues(person);

    }

    static List<ObjectField> GetPropertyValues(object obj)
    {
        List<ObjectField> propList = new List<ObjectField>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value = pinfo.GetValue(obj, null);

            if (pinfo.PropertyType.IsArray)
            {
                var arr = value as object[];
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (arr[i].GetType().IsPrimitive)
                    {
                        propList.Add(new ObjectField() { Name = pinfo.Name + i.ToString(), Value = arr[i].ToString() });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var lst = GetPropertyValues(arr[i]);
                        if (lst != null && lst.Count > 0)
                            propList.AddRange(lst);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (pinfo.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || value.GetType() == typeof(string))
                {
                    propList.Add(new ObjectField() { Name = pinfo.Name, Value = value.ToString() });
                }
                else
                {
                    var lst = GetPropertyValues(value);
                    if (lst != null && lst.Count > 0)
                        propList.AddRange(lst);
                }
            }
        }
        return propList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say that hardcoding and reflection don't mix.  Reflection is built strictly to AVOID hardcoding.

Comment: Andrew is correct. To avoid hardcoding you instead of checking for pinfo.Name == "Emails" just check that whether a property is premitive type or complex type. If it is complex type then iterate through all the properties of that complex type too. Or the other way is to implement ToString() method in the PersonEmails class which will create a string representation of the all the PersonEmail objects with all the values of properties Type and Value. You can give that string representation in JSON format also.

Comment: So, in order to identify a complex type, I've given a custom attribute to those properties.  I'm trying to get away from this "emails...", because I also have other objects nestled in there, such as Telephone Numbers.  (I only mentioned email to keep things simple).  So with this said, I'm stuck at `var **records** = pinfo.getValue(person,null) as object[];`. This should be `person.Emails`, but i want to keep it generic as possible, so can i do anything like person[pinfo.Name], using reflection once again?

Comment: @Mark: I have updated my answer. In this code I am getting values of property depending on the type of property i.e. whether it is premitive or non-premitive or array type. I used a recursive function to get values from non-premitive types until we get premitive or string type values at the bottom. You can modify this method to specify maxdepth to avoid stack overflow.

Comment: Hi Nitin, this is great, and it almost works perfectly. When it got down to the Email/Phone, it was adding { Name = "Type", Value = "Official" } & { Name = "Value", Value = "me@here.com" }, for each email address. this needed to be { Name = Type, Value = Value }.  I've managed to accomplish this by adding a custom class attribute to PersonEmail class, and looking for this attribute prior to getting the properties of the whole object, and then hard coding `var type = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Type").GetValue(obj, null)`, and adding a row for this. - Not true reflection however :(

Answer (score 1):

Check this snippet out:

```
if(pinfo.PropertyType.IsArray)
{
  // Grab the actual instance of the array.
  // We'll have to use it in a few spots.
  var array = pinfo.GetValue(personObject);

  // Get the length of the array and build an indexArray.
  int length = (int)pinfo.PropertyType.GetProperty("Length").GetValue(array);

  // Get the "GetValue" method so we can extact the array values
  var getValue = findGetValue(pinfo.PropertyType);

  // Cycle through each index and use our "getValue" to fetch the value from the array.
  for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    fields.Add(new ObjectField { Name = pinfo.Name, Value = getValue.Invoke(array, new object[]{i}).ToString();
}

// Looks for the "GetValue(int index)" MethodInfo.
private static System.Reflection.MethodInfo findGetValue(Type t)
{
  return (from mi in t.GetMethods()
    where mi.Name == "GetValue"
    let parms = mi.GetParameters()
    where parms.Length == 1
    from p in parms
    where p.ParameterType == typeof(int)
    select mi).First();
}
```

You can definately do it with `Reflection`... You can take advantage of the fact that a `Type` can tell you if it's an array or not (`IsArray`)... and then take advantage of the fact that an `Array` has a method `GetValue(int index)` that will give you a value back.

**Per your comment**

Because `Emails` is a property within a different class, recursion should be used.  However the trick is knowing when to go to the next level.  Really that is up to you, but
if it were me, I would use some sort of `Attribute`:

```
static void fetchProperties(Object instance, List<ObjectField> fields)
{
  foreach(var pinfo in instance.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
    if(pinfo.PropertyType.IsArray)
    {
      ... // Code described above
    }
    else if(pinfo.PropertyType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeAttribute), false).Any())
      // Go the next level
      fetchProperties(pinfo.GetValue(instance), fields);
    else
    {
      ... // Do normal code
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for this.  I'm getting an error on "Value = getValue..." ('getValue' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method')

Comment: @Mark sorry, it should have been `var getValue = ...`. I forgot the `var`.  I updated the answer.

Comment: I spotted that, but still getting the red squiggles :( `var getValue = FindGetValue(pinfo.PropertyType);`, `fields.Add(new ObjectField { Name = pinfo.Name, Value = getValue(array, new object[] { i }).ToString() });`

Comment: No, I assume `getValue(array, new object[]{i})` is calling the equivalent Array.GetValue method, and Value is being set to the result of this.  The error suggests getValue isn't a method that can be called, or it's missing something for it to recognise that it is.

Comment: Are we missing a .Invoke `getValue.Invoke(array, new object[] {i})`?

Comment: @Mark Ah, thats it... Thats what I get for winging it... It should be `getValue.Invoke(array, new object[]{i})`

Comment: I'm sure this will work, but it won't at the base level.  As you can see from my class above, the Array isn't till a level down, as it's contained within the Emails XElement. Your code is not finding the array.  I need to somehow go down a level before checking if it's an array