# Get property values from complex model in C#

Tags: asp.net-core, complextype, propertyinfo

I want to obtain the values of properties of a complex model (IList(Object) in object)). I find the the main properties of the parent object and also the type of the childobject which I need. But I cannot extract its values.

I think the issue is due to the obect parameter in the GetValue method. It needs to be the "TheMovieDatabaseModelDetails" object. I've tried a lot of various options here, but get the error: "object does not match target type".

Model:

```
public class TheMovieDatabaseModel
{
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int total_results { get; set; }
    public int total_pages { get; set; }
    public IList<TheMovieDatabaseModelDetails> results { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
private async Task GetMovieDetailsForTheMovieDatabase<T>(T movieModel)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = movieModel.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertyInfo)
            {
                if (property.Name.Equals("results"))
                {
                    var movieDetails = property.GetType().GetProperties();
                    foreach (var detail in movieDetails)
                    {
                        detail.GetValue(movieDetails, null); // here I need to fill in the right "object".
                    }
                }

                // etc..
            }
        }
```

research (amongst others):
[Get Values From Complex Class Using Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091452/get-values-from-complex-class-using-reflection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer in:

[C# object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438015/c-sharp-object-to-array)

I needed to created an IEnumerable first, as the parent model creates an IList of the ChildModel (movies, which have the moviedetails):

```
if (property.Name.Equals("results"))
                {
                    object movieObject = property.GetValue(movieModel);
                    IEnumerable movieObjectList = movieObject as IEnumerable;
                    if (movieObjectList != null)
                    {
                        foreach (object movie in movieObjectList)
                        {
                            PropertyInfo[] movieDetails = movie.GetType().GetProperties();
                            foreach (PropertyInfo detail in movieDetails)
                            {
                                detail.GetValue(movie, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please mark you own answer as accepted